# Where clause, column alias

Tags: mysql, database

I have a mysql datebase, and im trying to show in the results all the animals that are brown and are at most 2 years old. All i can get is this, and it is just displaying the age value, and not filtering it to <=2.

```
select name, DOB, 
truncate(datediff(sysdate(),DOB)/365.25,0) as 'age'
from animal
where colour = 'Brown' and 'age' <=2;
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: If you could set up an example on sqlfiddle.com, it would be much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not use this alias of select clause in where clause, do this repeate

```
select name, DOB, 
truncate(datediff(sysdate(),DOB)/365.25,0) as 'age'
from animal
where colour = 'Brown' and truncate(datediff(sysdate(),DOB)/365.25,0) <=2;
```

Comment: thank you, this helps alot. I need to hide the age column though, how can i do this?

Comment: thanks! 

select name, DOB
from animal
where colour = 'Brown' and truncate(datediff(sysdate(),DOB)/365.25,0) <2
ORDER BY DOB;

Comment: You should not be encouraging people to filter on calculated fields when it can be done against the DOB directly. This is a very poor solution as it cannot use indices! This will require a full table scan when it should be an index lookup.

Comment: Sorry, no. It was aimed at @Nirmal. He has given you a very poor solution as justified in my previous comment.

Comment: @nnichols: whats is other solution if one dont have required column, it is `only` solution according to his/her DB schema, you can suggest in this situation.

Comment: @Nirmal-thInkbeYond - age is directly related to date of birth. As you can see in my answer you can get the same result by filtering against DOB directly.

Answer (score 0):

You should do your filtering based on DOB not a calculated field -

```
SELECT name, DOB
FROM animal
WHERE colour = 'Brown'
AND DOB > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 YEAR);
```

**EDIT** In light of the accepted answer I feel the need to explain my answer.  The use of -

```
where colour = 'Brown' and truncate(datediff(sysdate(),DOB)/365.25,0) <=2;
```

as a method to filter age is not efficient as it requires the age to be calculated in order to do the comparison, rendering any index on the DOB column useless. Whereas, filtering on the DOB field directly can then use any applicable index -

```
DOB > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 YEAR);
```

This simply says "date of birth is greater than today minus three years". So a date of birth of '2009-03-22' and current date of '2012-03-22' will be evaluated as -

```
'2009-03-22' > ('2012-03-22' - INTERVAL 3 YEAR)
```

which in turn becomes -

```
'2009-03-22' > '2009-03-22'
```

which evaluates to false as the person is now 3 (today). Whereas, if the person's birthday is tomorrow ('2009-03-23') they are still 2 -

```
'2009-03-23' > ('2012-03-22' - INTERVAL 3 YEAR)
```

which in turn becomes -

```
'2009-03-23' > '2009-03-22'
```

which evaluates to true.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `HAVING age <= 2`.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Comment: thank you very much, but is there a way to not show the age column, just show the animals that are <=2?

Comment: use HAVING truncate(datediff(sysdate(),DOB)/365.25,0) <= 2